# SQL Server Database Diagram Connection Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, diagram

As you can see in the picture, I have the tables. The mistake I got is as follows: From the airport table, the primary key should go to both fields in the flight table. I get an error when I do this to both the stay airport and the landing airport. How do I solve this?

[image]

> Error: - Unable to create relationship 'FK_a.ucus_a.havalimanlari1'.
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_a.ucus_a.havalimanlari1' on table 'a.ucus' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: I removed multiple database tags. Please add the specific tag only.

Comment: It seems there's a defect in the UI tool you are using. It's perfectly normal to have multiple FK constraints between the same couple of tables. No need for `ON DELETE` or `ON UPDATE`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=130e4957b432ded806e54d2bf8a42d4a

Comment: Because you have enables cascade actions it is warning you that you can end up with a big mess. As @TheImpaler says in the second sentence remove `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` actions.